# Replace a word with another word in place based on the number of occurence

Tags: javascript, arrays, dictionary, join, split

I have a sentence:

```
Hello there how is it going? I am good, Is it hot? I get it.
```

Given the following: `[{"I", 2}, {"is": 1}]`, I want to convert the 2nd occurrence of the word `I` and replace it with: `<i>I</i>` and the 1st occurrence of the word `is` and replace it with `<i>is</i>` so now my final sentence is:

`Hello there how <i>is</i> it going? I am good, Is it hot? <i>I</i> get it`.

The key is the word I want to replace and the value is the position at which I want to replace that word.

My attempt:

```
let sentence = "Hello there how is it going? I am good, Is it hot? I get it";
let keyValuePair = [{"I", 2}, {"is": 1}];
keyValuePair.map(value => {
  for (let k in value) {
    sentence = sentence.split(k).join('<b>'+  k + '</b>');
  }
});
```

The above does not consider splitting word but characters and the position.

Answer (score 0):

You could iterate the replacement array and count the occurence and replace if necessary.

```js
var string = 'Hello there how is it going? I am good, Is it hot? I get it.';

string =  [{ I: 2 }, { is: 1 }].reduce((s, o) => {
    var count = 0,
        key = Object.keys(o)[0],
        value = o[key];
        
    return s.replace(new RegExp('\\b' + key + '\\b', 'g'), s => ++count === value ? '<i>' + s + '</i>': s);
}, string);

console.log(string);
```